# Maintaining thumbnails in Premiere CC

Tags: premiere, cc, thumbnails

When I open a bin containing video files in Premiere CC on a Mac, if I want to view the video files as thumbnails, I have to wait quite a few seconds every time.  Is there a setting so that I can cache these thumbnail views somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried using proxies for large video files?

Answer (score 1):

- Allocate as much RAM to Premiere as possible (in the settings), and, as Kazanaki suggested, learn to use proxies (lower resolution copies of your master files).